# Can' call Socket.on() in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets

I want to use nodeJS in my PHP web app. I followed the nodejs tutorial and that works fine when I run on `localhost:3000` but I want to run on `url` like this `localhost/final/chat/chat_index.html` file. So What I did is following code

**chat_index.html**

```
<div id="newUser">
  <form id="user">
    <input id="username">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/final/chat/chat_index.html',
                        {resource:'https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js'});

$('#user').submit(function(){
socket.emit('new user', $('#username').val());
});

}); // document.ready ends here
</script>
```

**index.js** This is server side JS file

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/final/chat/chat_index.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat_index.html');
});



io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('connected user');

   socket.on('new user', function(user){
       console.log(user);
   });  
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('listening to port');
});
```

Above `chat_index.html` page loads which shows the form on it. When I submit some data through this form server side js is not getting the data.

Is something missing in my code or I am doing something wrong in my code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is solved `io.of('/final/chat/chat_index.html')` should be used before `io` methods

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to run socket on an specific route, you can use *room/namespace*

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#

**Example ( server )**

```
var finalChat = io.of("/final/chat");
finalChat.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('connected user');

  socket.on('new user', function(user){
    console.log(user);
  });  
});
```

If you want Independence private chat rooms, you may want to use `id` base socket rooms

Comment: Thats what I did in my code Please see the comment and edited question. Anyways Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Which version of express are you using? I believe in express 4 it should be:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
```

On the client side could you also try using:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

then load the resource in as a script tag?